# How can I change Bootstrap tabs on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I think it's a very basic question, but I really couldn't make it work.
I'm trying to make the bootstrap tabs change when the mouse hovers over them.

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav class="nav nav-tabs"> <!--nav-pills deixa parecido com o menu e tira o efeito de abas-->
        <button data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#abaEle" class="nav-link active" type="button">Eletronicos</button>
        <button data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#abaMas" class="nav-link" type="button">Moda Masculina</button>
        <button data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#abaFem" class="nav-link" type="button">Moda Feminina</button>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="abaEle">
            Conteudo da aba eletronicos
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="abaMas">
            Conteudo da aba moda masculina
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="abaFem">
            Conteudo da aba moda feminina
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".nav-link").mouseenter(function() {
            var target = $(this).attr('data-bs-target');
            $(target).tab('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were overcomplicating things a bit. You just need `$(this).tab('show');` on the hover:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-link").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav nav-tabs">
    <!--nav-pills deixa parecido com o menu e tira o efeito de abas-->
    <button data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#abaEle" class="nav-link active" type="button">Eletronicos</button>
    <button data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#abaMas" class="nav-link" type="button">Moda Masculina</button>
    <button data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#abaFem" class="nav-link" type="button">Moda Feminina</button>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="abaEle">
      Conteudo da aba eletronicos
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="abaMas">
      Conteudo da aba moda masculina
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="abaFem">
      Conteudo da aba moda feminina
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: aeeee Obrigada (: